# how to move a pivot chart with vba

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, pivot-chart

i am trying to make a function that creates a chart next to the pivot table but cant make the chart move =(    display the right data and works fine, its just been created to far away from the actual pivot table.

```
Function chart_from_pivot(a_pivot As PivotTable) As Chart
Debug.Print 0

Dim objChart As Chart
Set objChart = Charts.Add

Debug.Print 1

objChart.SetSourceData a_pivot.TableRange1
Debug.Print 2
objChart.ChartType = xl3DColumn
Debug.Print 3
objChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=a_pivot.Parent.Name
Debug.Print 4

'HERE IS THE ISSUE!!!!
'objChart.Parent.Left = Range("D2").Left
'Debug.Print 5
'objChart.Parent.Top = Range("D2").Top
'Debug.Print 6

'objChart.ChartStyle = 294
'Debug.Print 7

chart_from_pivot = objChart
```

End Function

any recommendations?   thanks guys.

Comment: If left to itself, the chart goes to the center of the screen near where the cursor was last in your spreadsheet.  Try setting a cursor location first in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to set the objchart with the objchart.Location  once i added the set now it works =)

this is the final code in case some one needed in the future.

```
Function chart_from_pivot(a_pivot As PivotTable) As Chart
    Dim objChart As Chart
    Set objChart = Charts.Add

    objChart.SetSourceData a_pivot.TableRange1
    objChart.ChartType = xl3DColumn
    Set objChart = objChart.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=a_pivot.Parent.Name)

    objChart.ChartStyle = 294

    objChart.ChartArea.Left = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Charts").Range("B10").Left
    objChart.ChartArea.Top = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Charts").Range("B10").Top   
    chart_from_pivot = objChart
End Function
```